# Bad week of year in Java

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I have problem with correct week of year. I have JTextField, where I enter date in format DD.MM.YYYY.

```
private void buttonAddCulturalActionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    String date = textfieldDateOfEvent.getText();
    if (!isCorrectFormatDate(date)) {
        textareaExtract.append("Wrong date format!\n");
        return;
    }
    int day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5));
    int year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6, 10));
    GregorianCalendar enteredDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    String actionName = textfieldActionName.getText();
    String placeActionName = textfieldPlaceActionName.getText();
    int startHourAction = Integer.parseInt(textfieldStartHourAction.getText());

    if (isAllEntered(actionName, enteredDate, placeActionName, startHourAction)) {
        CulturalAction newAction = new CulturalAction(actionName, enteredDate,
                placeActionName, startHourAction);
        // culturalActions is priority queue
        culturalActions.add(newAction);
        extractAction(newAction);
    } else {
        textareaExtract.append("You need entered all parameters!\n");
    }
}
```

Here I set the cultural action (in constructor):

```
public CulturalAction(String nameAction, GregorianCalendar dateAction, String placeAction, int startHourAction) {
    this.nameAction = nameAction;
    this.placeAction = placeAction;
    this.startHourAction = startHourAction;
    // I have private attribute numberOfWeek in class CulturalAction
    cisloTydne = dateAction.get(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}
```

When I entered date 10.10.2013 and it would return the week number 45, but 40 is properly. I'm from Czech Republic.

Thank you for advices!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
GregorianCalendar enteredDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
```

That's going to be calling `new GregorianCalendar(2013, 10, 10)` - which means November, not October.

From the [`GregorianCalendar` constructor docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> `month` - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field in the calendar. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

Two other bits of advice:

- If you *have* to use just the Java libraries, use `SimpleDateFormat` to perform the parsing, rather than doing it yourself
- If you possibly can, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, which is a much more sensible API

Comment: Thank you for reply. I once again find fault entirely different type. I try to use SimpleDateFormat. Many thanks!

Comment: I have one more question about SimpleDateFormat. I now use this method to control correct date format:

[link](http://2i.cz/3001f2d80b)

When I enter date in wrong format dd.MM.yy (10.10.20) for example, program faults. Why?

Comment: @avalagne: What do you mean by "faults"? If you mean "it throws ParseException" then that's exactly what it's meant to do if you give it unparsable data. The fact that your code *swallows* `ParseException` means you're losing that information. Don't do that. *Never* swallow exceptions like that, without even logging.

Comment: Fault is StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. So how should I treat the entered date? I need that when a user enters the wrong date, the program did not fall and called it by another attempt to enter. This can be achieved just by using exception or not?

Comment: I save substring from date as year, which expected 4 characters, but when user enter only two, program faults with StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. I  don't know how else to treat.

Comment: @avalagne: It sounds like you should ask a new question with *details* about that. I can't really help without seeing the code *and where it fails*. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "10.10.2013" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu" ) )
         .get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR )
```

> 41

## Define 'week'

A week can be defined in various ways.

As you do not define your week, I will go with a standard [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601_week_date).

## Avoid legacy classes

Both the Question and the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16225699/642706) by Jon Skeet use old outdated date-time classes. The modern approach uses the java.time classes instead.

Parse the input string in its entirety. In real work, catch the exception from the parse attempt in case the input is not in expected format.

```
String input = "10.10.2013" ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

### `IsoFields`

Use the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR) class to extract the week of week-based-year number.

```
int week = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
```

> 41

## ThreeTen-Extra `YearWeek`

Also, consider adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. It offers a handy [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class to represent ISO 8601 weeks.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( ld ) ;
```

> yw.toString(): 2013-W41